# How does a WCF proxy implement ICommunicationObject if it's methods aren't visible?

Tags: wcf, interface, channelfactory, implements

How does a WCF channel (created via ChannelFactory) implement ICommunicationObject, but doesn't expose the Close() method, for example, unless you cast the proxy to ICommunicationObject? Does that make sense?

I got to thinking about that on the way home today and couldn't figure it out in my head. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question? Maybe I'm asking a stupid question? :)

Is it some kind of ninja trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done via [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Suppose you have an interface, like so:

```
public interface IFoo
{
     void Foo();
}
```

You can implement this normally:

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
     public void Foo() {} // Implicit interface implementation
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the interface members *explicitly*, which requires the cast:

```
public class Baz : IFoo
{
     void IFoo.Foo() {} // This will require casting the object to IFoo to call
}
```

This can be very useful at times. For example, it is often done to implement `IDisposable` in classes where the preferred API would be to call `.Close()`, for example.  By implementing `IDisposable` explicitly, you "hide" the `Dispose()` method, but still allow the class instance to be used via a using statement.

Comment: Thanks, Reed and Dan! First post wins.

Answer (score 2):

The `Channel` class implements the `ICommunicationObject` interface explicitly.  Here's an example demonstrating the difference between explicit interface implementation and implicit interface implementation:

```
internal interface IExample
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class ImplicitExample : IExample
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class ExplicitExample : IExample
{
    void IExample.DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    void Demo()
    {
        var explicitExample = new ExplicitExample();
        // explicitExample.DoSomething(); <-- won't compile
        ((IExample)explicitExample).DoSomething(); // <-- compiles

        var implicitExample = new ImplicitExample();
        implicitExample.DoSomething(); // <-- compiles
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the an MSDN article on this subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx